# extjs//extjs4// Why I can't see some methods?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm student study Extjs4!

I make Ext.form.Panel

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title : 'panel',
        region : 'center',
        layout : 'absolute',
        margins : '5 5 0 5',
        id : 'designSpace',
        items : this.arrayItem
    });
```

And After Time, I use this var, and find method,

but I can't see some method! like panel.add, panel.doLayout.

I must need this Method!

It is explain in extjs4 document.. but I can't use it...

How can i use this Method..?

I use Spket Plugin's Code Assist.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details?   You can't see the methods via Code Assist?  You can't see the methods when you console.log(panel)?  Please provide the code where you are trying to use these methods.

Comment: Thanks justin, i use spket in Eclipse, but he did not all code assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you call these methods? If you just don't see them in log, it might be ok.

Comment: Thanks sha! You helped me before. When i study GXT! I solve this problem. I use spket in eclipse, but he didn't all code assist!